# Modifying element styling on THTMLViewer

Tags: html, delphi

I'm using THTMLViewer on Delphi and I need to modify some styling, says the font color or background color, after the HTML is loaded. How do I achieve that if I know the element ID only? I guess it's somehow related to IDDisplay, but cannot find any clue whatsoever in help files and demos. Consider I have this html:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <span id="text1">This is text 1</span>
    <a href="#" id="link1">This is link 1</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I want to change, for example text1 color to red, what should I do?

Comment: You could add a stylesheet (.css file): `#text1 { color: #00F; }`. Read more about stylesheets/CSS and how to style a HTML file. There is **a lot of information** on the web.

Comment: it's not about HTML styling, it's about HTML element manipulation on a THTMLViewer component in delphi

Comment: Your title is "Modifying element styling". Well, if you want to change the colour of the span with ID text1 to red, you do it with CSS, either by changing the HTML (`<span id="text1" style="color: #F00">`) or by applying an external stylesheet.

Comment: My title is "Modifying element styling on THTMLViewer", it's another world than just "Modifying elemen styling"

Comment: HTMLViewer also allows you to use CSS, so what is the problem? The way to change the colour of a HTML element in THmtlViewer is also through CSS, AFAIK.

Comment: Any idea on how to change the CSS attribs *AFTER* the THTMLViewer loaded/rendered the HTML? I don't know, maybe something like HTMLViewer.GetElement(elementid).Font.Color := RGB(255,0,0);

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the HTML when it is loaded. An example that can do this is below.

If you need more styling, than simply add a `<head>` with a `<style>` element specifying a CSS file or direct styles directly after the `<html>` tag.

Here is what I tried and what worked for your example. You must implement the `OnParseBegin` event:

```delphi
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Of course you can also load from file or stream or URL:
  HtmlViewer1.LoadFromString(
    '<html>' +
    '  <body>' +
    '    <h1>Yay! This works!</h1>' + 
    '    <p>This paragraph is not red.</p>' +
    '    <p><span id="text1">This is text 1.</span> this comes after it.</p>' +
    '    <p><a href="#" id="link1">This is link 1</a>.</p>' +
    '    <p>This paragraph is normal too.</p>' + 
    '  </body>' +
    '</html>');
end;

procedure TForm2.HtmlViewer1ParseBegin(Sender: TObject; var Source: TBuffer);
var
  S: string;
  B: TBuffer;
begin
  S := Source.AsString;

  // Add inline styling.
  S := StringReplace(S, 'id="text1"', 'id="text1" style="color: Red"', []);

  B := TBuffer.Create(S);
  try
    Source.Assign(B);
  finally
    B.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Now we're talking. As I write earlier, I need to change the style *AFTER* the HTML loaded, in other word, doing it on OnParseBegin cannot be done, as OnParseBegin occurs before the HTML completely loaded or rendered, whatever terms used. Consider this script:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HtmlViewer1.LoadFromString('<html><head></head><body><a id="link1" href="link1" color="#00ff00">This is red link, click this link to change it to green</a></body></html>');
end;

procedure TForm1.HtmlViewer1HotSpotClick(Sender: TObject; const SRC: string;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if HtmlViewer1.LinkAttributes.Values['href']='link1' then
  begin
    MessageBox(0,'This link event is captured, but how to change the text color here?','Some Title',0);
  end;
end;
```

...

Of course I can just easily write script to reload the HTMLViewer in OnHotSpotClick with the element style (i.e: color) changed to green. But it's seems too much if not overkill to reload entire body of HTML just for modifying an element. I look for something similar one can be done with jQuery, for example

```
<script>
  function changeText(obj) {
    $(obj).css(color,'#00ff00');
  }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="changeText(this); return false;" style="color:#ff0000;">This is red text, click here to change it to green</a>
```